# jQuery UI dialog only opens once in Chrome, will not close in IE 10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a strange problem with a jQuery UI dialog only opening once in Chrome, while it won't close in IE 10.
Here is the HTML containing the dialog itself:

```
<td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelWithTooltip(model => model.AuditDto.Scope)</td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AuditDto.Scope)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuditDto.Scope)
        <div id="scope-modal-editor">
            @Html.TextArea("ScopeEditor", @Model.AuditDto.Scope, new {@class="popup-editor"})
        </div>   
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the javascript I use to create and open the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scope-modal-editor').dialog({
            title: 'Edit Scope',
            autoOpen: false,
            appendTo: 'body',
            show: 'fade',
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            modal: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "OK",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#AuditDto_Scope").val($("#ScopeEditor").val());
            }
        }),
        $('#AuditDto_Scope').focus(function (e) {
            $('#scope-modal-editor').dialog('open');

        });
```

Each time #AuditDto_Scope gets focus, the dialog should open. This, as I said, only happens once.

I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.3 and jQuery 2.0.3. Can anyone see something wrong here, or could it be a bug in one of the frameworks?

UPDATE: Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the exact issue: http://jsfiddle.net/C9KTt/1/

Comment: make a fiddle of it at : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9KTt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final answer!**
This code is alot better for what you are trying to achieve:

```
$('#scope').focus(function (e) {
    var $dialog = $('#scope-modal-editor');
    if($dialog.dialog( "isOpen" ) === false)
        $dialog.dialog('open');

});
```

Here is the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9KTt/7/

---

**Older answers:**

If you change it to:

```
$('#scope').click(function (e) {
    $('#scope-modal-editor').dialog('open');
});
```

Then it works fine in Chrome.
The problem is that the "focus" event gets fired 3 times, when you first focus the textarea, which must cause some sort of bug in the dialog.

This works in both Chrome and IE: http://jsfiddle.net/C9KTt/6/

Note that I changed the jquery version, as the 2.0.2 was throwing "Access Denied" errors in IE 10

<strike>Also if you REALLY need the onfocus event you could wrap it like this instead:</strike>

```
(function(){
    var timeoutId;
    $('#scope').focus(function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
             $('#scope-modal-editor').dialog('open');
        }, 100);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Why do you think focus is better than click? Is focus better supported?

Comment: It depends on what you need it for. I would personally choose click. But as you were using focus in your code, I tried to accommodate that, as I though you had a reason for doing it. 
Focus will fire when a user tabs to the textarea, Click will not. So if that is an issue, I would continue using focus if I was you, otherwise I'd prefer Click.

Comment: Good input. Focus would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your first question, e.g. in chrome it only opens once. Does it means that if you open and close it, and then try to open it then it's not opening it again?

IE is having issue with dialog.
This is a in-built problem for jQuery UI dialog. Probably what is happening is that (in IE) that multiple DOM reference is creating. In IE while the dialog is not closing check for element "scope-modal-editor" using developer tool.
I am sure you will find multiple instances of that. So next time when you are trying to close the dialog the operation is actually targeting a false reference.

Try to use functions like

```
$(element).dialog("close");
```

and

```
$(element).dialog('destroy');
```

You can also try to remove the element from DOM and re-create it dynamically by calling 
`$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()` function.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct about the behavior. Andre´s answer above seems to have solved the issue for both Chrome and IE. I will however look at your suggestions if I get into new issues with dialog.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery(this).dialog('destroy').remove();

Comment: Welcome @Tatinfo, could you elaborate a bit more on your answer?